# Syntax error: <a> link not working by clicking, only opens by right click + "open link in new tab" command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

When I click the 'Download Full Menu' link in this page (http://www.brazenbbq.com/menus/restaurant/) it won't open unless I right click and 'Open link in a new tab'. I used Chrome and Firefox element inspector and I get the below Jquery error, but I'm not sure how can I fix it since I'm just a javascript newbie... Thank you for your help!

```js
2jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:formatted:570

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Brazen_BBQ_Menu.pdf

fa.error @ jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:formatted:570

fa.tokenize @ jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:formatted:898

fa.select @ jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:formatted:1069

fa @ jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:formatted:339

find @ jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:formatted:1188

n.fn.init @ jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:formatted:1211

n @ jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:formatted:22

(anonymous function) @ VM266:43

dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:formatted:2128

r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:formatted:2007
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line in the script ( animate scroll down to anchor script  ) you have

```
    $leftMenu(".fullMenuLeft a").on("click", function( e ) {

    e.preventDefault();
```

that's why your first link to pdf  doesn't work as you want. plus...in the continuation of the script you use the `href` of `this` ...which is the `fullMenuleft a` href to do something different than what you expect from pdf link to do

so change the above line to

```
  $leftMenu(".fullMenuLeft li:not(.menuTitle) a").on("click", function( e ) {

  e.preventDefault();
```

so you will select all the `li a` except the first one , the one with link to pdf

Comment: @JuanF.Blanco glad i could help .DON'T forget to accept this as the answer. :) thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `target="_blank"` in your `a` tag

```
<a href="link.pdf" target="_blank">Some Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have javascript that is hooking into the nav, expecting a #Item to link to (scrolls down).

The link to the PDF is also in this nav, and so your jQuery plugin (or custom code) is trying to parse the "hash" (that it hasn't found) and then fails....

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on 'download full menu' your sticky menu-navigation plugin tries to scroll to the according position on the page. But as this download-link is not an anchor, Javascript throws an error. Try to change your click-handler selector to something like this:

```
$leftMenu(".fullMenuLeft a[href~='#']").on("click", function( e ) { ... }
```

With the attribute selector and tilde you can filter your links by the hash in the href attribute.